# Drupal: Views cache and memcached

Tags: drupal, view, memcached

I'm using memcached with the page max set to 15 minutes. Does this mean that views cache is pointless? If I have a 5 minute views cache, it would be meanginless because the page itself wouldn't update for 15 minutes, is that how it goes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how your site is used. If it is predominantly visited by anonymous users, then they will typically only see cached content from the page cache (served, in your case, by memcached). However, if you have many authenticated users, the views cache can still serve to cache things (queries and rendered output) that aren't normally cached for authenticated users. The block cache similarly benefits authenticated users, but is redundant for anonymous users.